# Make a div focused and everything else dark using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need this widget for Angular:
https://github.com/zzarcon/focusable

I need to be able to focus a div, make everything outside it dark and not able to click outside. I need to draw my user attention only to the div.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to create a directive which uses the jQuery lib you suggested:

```
myApp.directive('myFocusableDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            Focusable.setFocus(elem);
        }
    };
});

<div my-focusable-directive>
    I AM FOCUSABLE!
</div>
```